# STL map find doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm having a map containing 1323 records, which is getting filled the following way:

```
std::map<uint32_t, House*> m_houses;
[...]

void OnReceiveHousePacket(HouseTable_t* recvTable, int32_t size) {
     m_houses.clear();

     for (int32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++recvTable) {
          House* h = new House;
          memcpy(&h->table, recvTable, sizeof (HouseTable_t));
          m_houses.insert(std::make_pair(recvTable->clientId, h));
     }
}
```

The issue I'm having with this, is that when I am trying to find a record by key:

```
const House* Get(uint32_t clientId) {
    auto it = m_houses.find(clientId);

    if (it == m_houses.end()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return it->second;
}
```

It returns `nullptr`, although the key exists and I am sure about that.

`m_houses.count(clientId)` returns 0 as well

However, when I change the `Get([...])` function contents to the following loop, everything works like a charm without any issues which proves that the record really exists in the map:

```
for (const auto& h : m_houses) {
     if (h.first == clientId) {
          return h.second;
     }
}

return nullptr;
```

It's the first time I am having an issue like that with STL's map.

What is the problem? I've always been using this way to find a record and never faced such issue.

### edit

`HouseTable_t` and `House`:

```
struct HouseTable_t {
    char name[24 + 1];
    char owner[64 + 1];

    int clientId;
    int type;
    int rank;
    unsigned char identifier;
}

class House{
public:
    House() = default;

    HouseTable_t m_table;
    int id;
    int data;
};
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `House` and `HouseTable_t` and why are you `memcpy`ing to a pointer?

Comment: @user657267 It doesn't really matter for this particular case, but as you can see from the function name it's being sent by packet and I am retrieving it like that.

Comment: With that `memcpy`, you're leaking memory and losing track of the `House` object you allocated in the previous line.

Comment: It *really does matter* because it makes no sense, you create a new `House` and then in the very next line you overwrite the pointer value. Why are you even using `memcpy` in C++?

Comment: Since you clear `m_houses` at the start of every `OnReceiveHousePacket`, I'd say the problem is that you're receiving an empty packet.

Comment: @user657267 `House` and `HouseTable_t` are structs simple structs with few `int` and `string` data types. Regarding your question; are there any reasons why I shouldnt use it with C++?

Comment: @MarkRansom Then why the record is being found by the loop?

Comment: By `string` do you mean `std::string`? Because that can't be `memcpy`d at all as it's not trivially copyable, besides you're copying a struct to a *pointer* which is nonsensical. Post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user657267 See my edit, added the struct.

Comment: Now that you've fixed your example: [Cannot replicate](https://ideone.com/cO18uT).

Comment: Also RE: `memcpy`:  `h->table = *recvTable`

Comment: @user657267 I know that, thats why I am wondering. This might help though: the only keys out of 1323 being found in the `m_houses` table through the map find are... http://pastebin.com/raw/F4kNgYNU and they are invalid (still everything works fine when using the loop)

Comment: @Lucas The code in that pastebin did not produce that output, `uint32_t` is unsigned. Stop posting fake code and write up a new question with a **complete**, **minimal** example that compiles and displays the issue, anything else is mostly a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: There is no way the code at the top goes with the class definitions at the bottom.

Comment: Also how did you pass the `recvTable` parameter to `OnReceiveHousePacket()`?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
memcpy(&h, ...
```

Should be:

```
memcpy(h, ...
```

Otherwise you're trashing the pointer.

Comment: Which invokes undefined behavior, which trashes the value of the key that's being inserted...

Comment: Getting an error then `cannot convert 'HouseTable_t' to 'void*' for argument '1' to 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)'`

Comment: @Lucas: This code did not produce that error. Maybe this code did: `memcpy(h->table, ...` -- Please don't present fake code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I am sorry. I've been trying to provide as much informations as possible and made some mistakes during posting.

Comment: @Lucas: That's what copy/paste is for.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Now everything is corrected, though I think it's too late since this will be closed soon. *Sigh*